# Is there an appengine datastore namespace and socket connection relationship

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, namespaces, connection, datastore

I have used app-engine for 7 years and written several Java applications.

My new app uses namespace (my first foray into using this feature) to allow multi-tenanting. Apart from that new feature the code remains the same. Yet in the development server (do not know about production) the local network connection sometimes gets hung up and takes about 2 minutes to release the connection.

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: Interrupted while waiting on semaphore:
>          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:201)
>          at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:210)
>          at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:106)
>          at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.makeCall(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:178)
>          at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.makeCall(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:160)
>          at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$BaseRpcBatcher.makeCalls(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:78)

and

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:198)
>           at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:210)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:106)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.makeCall(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:178)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.makeCall(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:160)

Is there any chance (reported or not) the namespace global setting is confusing the socket that must be set up for the network connection.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are tones of with name namespaces there is even Google Namespaces API but its no longer recommended. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/multitenancy#App_Engine_APIs_that_use_namespaces Could you please specify what exactly you are using?

Comment: I am using **com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager** method **set** which sets a singleton global which is referenced globally by KeyFactory and Query. Thanks for the request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The network failure just happened on a non-namespace application.  I realize now I had not changed my software but had upgraded to Google Cloud SDK 292.0.0. Not sure if this is the issue.  Will create a new question.  Treat this as solve and closed in relationship to the namespace.